# i am trying to use an input from the user as part of a connection string to a SQL database

Tags: sql, vb.net, string

my connection string is saved in a string variable names str 
what i am trying to do is use an input from the user as part of the string
the parts i want to take from the user are the ID and PASS
i am simply trying to check the connection statues with the ID and the PASS as inputs from the user.

```
Dim str As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP;uid=ID;pwd=PASS;database=DB"
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(str)
Private Sub btnconnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnconnect.Click
    PW = txtadminpass.Text

    Try
        conn.Open()
        conn.Close()
        MsgBox("GOOD")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

i haven't had much like while using the + and & for the strings.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can check stringbuilder https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to check if the user is allowed to log into the database or not. The way you have followed looks good, you define the connection string based on the given ID and password, and you try to establish a connection, if it fails, the user can't log in, else he can do that.

However, the way you defined the string is wrong, you must use `concatenation` to preserve the ID and password values, try this,

```
Dim str As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP; uid=" & ID & "; pwd=" & PASS & ";database=DB"
```

Comment: It's `&` in VB rather than `+`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not a VB developer, but I have provided a generic template, he may replace the + with the &.

Comment: Thank you so much , this is exactly what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 3):

The [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an appropriate class to use in this case. You can add parts of the connection string to it via properties, so there is no chance of making mistakes:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim csb As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        csb.DataSource = "DESKTOP"
        csb.InitialCatalog = "DB"
        csb.UserID = "z"
        csb.Password = "x"
        ' output "Data Source=DESKTOP;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=z;Password=x" '
        Console.WriteLine(csb.ToString())
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, which makes it easy to read:

```
Const CONN_STRING As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP;uid={0};pwd={1};database=DB"

Dim connString As String = String.Format(CONN_STRING, txtUserID.Text.Trim, txtPassword.Text)
```